# Can I use this disconnect between meter pan and main panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding-and-bonding

I'm planning to add a disconnect on the outside of my house between a meter pan and my 100A main panel (inside). This is a follow up question to an [earlier question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/291973/adding-emergency-or-service-disconnect). After I've added the disconnect I will replace my main panel and upgrade it to 200A. The meter pan and utility wiring is already 200A. The idea of initially just installing a disconnect is that I do the following in one day:

1. Get utility to disconnect me
2. Install disconnect switch
3. Get inspected and approved
4. Have utility re-connect power

After that is complete I can work on my main panel upgrade without needing to coordinate with the utility.

The plan is to first install this disconnect as an emergency disconnect, but not as a service disconnect (230.85(b)(3). So that I don't have to redo grounds and neutrals in my existing panel. I bought the following disconnect: [Q2200MBRE](https://www.se.com/us/en/product/Q2200MRBE/circuit-breaker-enclosure-powerpact-q-200a-main-breaker-25ka-air-nema-3r). Unfortunately the label states "Suitable only for use as service equipment". This is puzzling to me, because it does have a green bonding screw, and when I remove the bonding screw the neutral lug is isolated from the enclosure. The description has this section:

> These rainproof Residential Enclosed Circuit Breakers are suitable for use only as service equipment since they feature a service entrance barrier, factory installed neutral bar bonded to the enclosure, factory applied emergency disconnect, and service entrance labels

But their manual also shows: bonding screw (if required) see picture below.

Is there any way I can use this without the bonding screw and keep my main-bonding-jumper in my existing main panel? Once I switch out the new main panel, I will do the bonding in the outside disconnect switch.

Edit: looking at the 2020 and 2023 code for section 230.85 I noticed that the 2023 language specifically says:

> "Other listed disconnect switch or circuit breaker that is marked
> suitable for use as service equipment, **but not marked as suitable only
> for use as service equipment,** installed on the supply side of each
> service disconnect"

My permit is still under the 2017 code, so this shouldn't impact me, but I'm still puzzled why they added that language.

[image: Panel label]
[image: Image from manual showing removable screw]

Answer (score 3):

### An emergency disconnect upstream of the service disconnect is bonded, just like anything else upstream of the service disconnect

In emergency-disconnect applications, the labeling of "Suitable *only* for use as service equipment" is a misnomer (it predates the NEC emergency-disconnect rule).  Why? Because just like a meter pan or tapbox upstream of the service disconnecting means, the emergency disconnect case is bonded using the *neutral* as per NEC 250.92(B).  So go ahead, fit the bonding screw, and use the box.

Comment: That makes sense. It seems like as long as I don't connect any grounds in the box, it will just have the neutral bonded to the case (via the screw) and will not be a service disconnect. I'm planning to use a 2" rigid offset coupling between the meter base and this enclosure. Should the jumper from the bonding bushing connect to the small neutral lugs(next to the large ones)?

Comment: I added a note to the original post, showing how the 2023 code specifically excludes "Suitable only for use as service equipment". Still puzzled why they did this.

Comment: @ChristianK -- I'll have to do some more research on when that was introduced o.O